Convert CSV file to shapefile
I've been trying to save my CSV file as a shapefile, but every time I attempt to do so, I encounter an error that says Storing metadata for the specified URI is not supported. I've double-checked the file path, ensured the file names are correct, and attempted to save using different methods like GeoPackage, ESRI shapefile, and SpatiaLite (SQLite), but the issue persists. I've also verified the coordinates.
How can I fix this problem?
CSV data is like:
SitRecID, SpcHisFamName, SpcHisSciName, SpcHisCommonName, SpcHisCategory, SeaDesc, CtyBirdLifeName, ibaStaDesc, SitLat, SitLong
6840, Anatidae Dendrocygna, viduata, White-faced Whistling-duck, LC, non-breeding, Senegal, confirmed, 16.33333333, -16.25 
6840, Anatidae Dendrocygna, bicolor, Fulvous Whistling-duck, LC, non-breeding, Senegal, confirmed, 16.33333333, -16.25
6841, Anatidae Dendrocygna, bicolor, Fulvous Whistling-duck, LC, non-breeding, Senegal, confirmed, 16.15, -16.2


what does your CSV look like?

Where do you want to save it? Try a local drive where you have writing permission.

this is how my csv looks like: SitRecID SpcHisFamName SpcHisSciName SpcHisCommonName SpcHisCategory SeaDesc CtyBirdLifeName ibaStaDesc SitLat SitLong
6840 Anatidae Dendrocygna viduata White-faced Whistling-duck LC non-breeding Senegal confirmed 16.33333333 -16.25
6840 Anatidae Dendrocygna bicolor Fulvous Whistling-duck LC non-breeding Senegal confirmed 16.33333333 -16.25
6841 Anatidae Dendrocygna bicolor Fulvous Whistling-duck LC non-breeding Senegal confirmed 16.15 -16.2

I want to save it on my computer. I have already created a file where I initially saved the CSV, and I also want to use the same file for the Shapefile

Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. Comments are meant to be ephemeral, and do not have the formatting capabilities to make that information legible.

Works for me no problem with QGIS

I have no problem importing the csv as point layer into QGIS and exporting it as Geopackage. You should tell as a little bit more about what you do. Does the imported csv layer show correctly as points layer in your QGIS?

Do you have writing permissions on the drive? Disk is full? Try another location for saving.

Have you added metadata for the imported layer with QGIS?

Try unchecking the "Persist layer metadata option". That prevents the creation of .qmd file. That was not a problem for me when I tried exporting to shapefile, though.
